# Angular CLI project with Lazy Loading route configuration in library

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a Angular 6 CLI workspace containig a library with feature modules. Every feature module contains its own routes, but I want the library routing module to be the parent - so the path should actually match the layout: libraryA/featureA.

The solution seems to be lazy loading the library module, but I can't get it working. I started off with a simple setup, I created a new Angular app with `ng new`, then I downloaded [Router sample](https://angular.io/generated/zips/router/router.zip) and copied all file from `router/src/app` to my `src/app` folder. Executing `ng build` revealed the first error:

`ERROR in Could not resolve module app/admin/admin.module relative to /E/git/my-app/src/app/app-routing.module.ts`

So I started to compare the router sample with my project and found diffs in tsconfig*.ts files. Router sample sets `baseUrl` in `src/tsconfig.app.json` and `src/tsconfig.spec.json`, where Angular CLI sets it in `tsconfig.ts` directly. So I changed it to match the router sample and it worked.

But howto get this working when e.g. `crisis-center` is a library (`ng generate library crisis-center`) and doesn't lie within `src/app`?

How must `baseUrl` be configured? How does `loadChildren` look like (e.g. `loadChildren: 'crisis-center/crisis-center.module#CrisisCenterModule'`)? The fact is, no matter what I try I'm stuck with the error message above saying `Could not resolve module relative to ...`.

I just added the problematic parts to my public repository at GitHub:

https://github.com/AndreasFagschlunger/o2xfs-angular/commit/8b0f8735d799943088e61a5c546e3c27d89f09b3

So you can `git checkout` and try for yourself, `ng build operator` works but `ng build` fails regardless what I set in `loadChildren` (app-routing.module.ts).

Best regards,
Billie

## Workaround

It can't be all wrong, since the a workaround is to load the modules synchronous, e.g. this works fine:

```
export function loadOperatorModule() {
  return OperatorModule;
}

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'operator',
    loadChildren: loadOperatorModule
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/operator', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

The same goes for feature module (cdm) within library module (operator), workaround works but no clue howto set `loadChildren` with a string value which doesn't produce a error during runtime:

`projects\operator\src\lib\operator-routing.module.ts` wants to lazy load
`projects\operator\src\lib\cdm\cdm.module.ts

```
{ path: 'cdm', loadChildren: 'cdm/cdm.module#CdmModule' }
{ path: 'cdm', loadChildren: 'lib/cdm/cdm.module#CdmModule' }
{ path: 'cdm', loadChildren: './cdm/cdm.module#CdmModule' }
```